# Force \addtocontents to be placed in the correct order

Tags: table-of-contents

I have something like this:

```
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{chap1}
\chapter{chap2}
\addtocontents{toc}{test}
\chapter{chap3}
```

and the ToC is produced like this

```
chap1
chap2
chap3
test
```

I was wondering how to force `test` to be placed in correct order (chap1, chap2, test, chap3).

Comment: We need a minimal example. In a rough test this works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I know I should have included a minimal working sample but couldnt make one, the original one is a huge text and I cant include that.

Answer (score 19):

The command `\addtocontents` is mainly intended to be used to enter formatting information (extra spacing, for example) not directly related to any particular actual line of contents of the ToC; if you want to introduce some text together with some information (such as the page number) and some formatting (such as the one used for a particuar sectional unit), then you might want to use `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{chap1}
\chapter{chap2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{test}
\chapter{chap3}

\end{document}
```

If used together with the `hyperref` package, a `\phantomsection` command should also be included to get the proper result for the hyperlinks in the table of contents and for the bookmarks.

EDIT: since you don't want the page number nor any special formatting for the text to be included, then you can use `\addtocontents`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{chap1}
\chapter{chap2}
\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip text\par}
\chapter{chap3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I have another question then. How would I remove dots and page number using \addcontentsline command? I use memoir class. With \addtocontents, I use \addtocontents{toc}{
 \protect\noindent test \protect\par
} but that wouldnt work with \addcontentsline.

Comment: @user5540: The information provided in this comment was crucial and you should have included it in your question. In this case, it would be better to use a `\addcontents` command; I'll update my answer with a nes example.

Comment: originally I used \addtocontents, which caused the problem of incorrect order. I tried your updated code and the problem is still there :( Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @user5540: If you have a huge document, you are probably using the `\include` command to insert chapter. If that is the case, you have encountered one of the oldest bugs in Latex. To work around this, insert the `\addtocontents` as the first line of the file (in the example Chap 3) before the `\chapter` command.

Comment: @Danie Els: Yes, I use \include and your trick fixes my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This answer explains why the `\addtocontents` fails and offers a solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10297/16069