# Using titletoc to redefine chapter toc entry as part number + chapter

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

I am trying to get the part number appended to a chapter within that part.
E.g. I would like to get:

```
I Part One
   I.1 Chapter One
   I.2 Chapter Two
II Part Two
   II.3 Chapter Three
   II.4 Chapter Four
```

I'm using `titlesec` with the `newparttoc` option and `titletoc`. I've read that part should be redefined w/ titlesec if I want titletoc to be able to access its components, so I have done so.

I should mention I do not want to change the format throughout the document (i.e. redefining `\thechapter`).

I redefined the chapter toc entry as:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]
{\vspace{1.2em}\bfseries}
{\thepart\thecontentslabel\hspace{1.5em}}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.
The result is:
[image: mwe_output]

I'd really appreciate any thoughts.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}

%% Titles
%
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\vspace{3pc}\raggedleft\scshape\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
  {0.2em}
  {\raggedleft\normalfont\scshape\huge}
  [\vspace{2pc}]

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\titlerule[2pt]\centering\scshape\bfseries\Huge}
  {Part \thepart}
  {0.5em}
  {\centering\normalfont\itshape\Huge}
  [\titlerule\vspace{1em}]


\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]
{\vspace{1.2em}\bfseries}
{\thepart\thecontentslabel\hspace{1.5em}}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}%[\hfill]%[ ]

\pagestyle{empty}

\title{ToC Test}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle

\mainmatter
\tableofcontents
\part{Part One}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\chapter{Chapter Two}

\part{Part Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\chapter{Chapter Four}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! But you don't want to add the part number to the chapter number in the chapter heading?

Comment: Thanks! No, I don't want it in the chapter heading. I just need it modified in the ToC. This is because in my working document I have a chapter (say Chapter Five) which is **not** in Part Two, and therefore would not have the part number appended, making it very clear it's outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want (changes are pointed out with `%% <-----` arrows)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}

%% Titles
%
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\let\oldthechapter\thechapter    %% <----------  
\def\thechapter{\thepart.\oldthechapter}  %% <--------
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\vspace{3pc}\raggedleft\scshape\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename~\oldthechapter}  %% <----------
  {0.2em}
  {\raggedleft\normalfont\scshape\huge}
  [\vspace{2pc}]

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\titlerule[2pt]\centering\scshape\bfseries\Huge}
  {Part \thepart}
  {0.5em}
  {\centering\normalfont\itshape\Huge}
  [\titlerule\vspace{1em}]


\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]
{\vspace{1.2em}\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace{1.5em}}   %% <---------
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}%[\hfill]%[ ]

\pagestyle{empty}

\title{ToC Test}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle

\mainmatter

\tableofcontents

\part{Part One}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\chapter{Chapter Two}

\part{Part Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\chapter{Chapter Four}

\end{document}
```

Explanation: since you didn't redefine `\thechapter`, when `\chapter{Chapter One}` writes to the `.toc` file it writes

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chapter One}{5}%
```

which when read-back to write the TOC, the value `\thecontentslabel` is replaced by `1` and `\thepart` is **empty**, resulting in what you saw.

In other words: the invocation of `\titlecontents` control how to format the stuff written in the `.toc` file, but **not** how the `.toc` file contents are written. And when you call `\tableofcontents` it is before the first `\part`, and so `\thepart` returns nothing.

To make it work with the chapter heading displaying different things from the TOC with `\titleformat`, instead of using `\thechapter` in `\titleformat` and ask the TOC to behave differently, we will modify and use `\thechapter` in the TOC and ask `\titleformat` to behave differently. Of course, this would mean that any running header with chapter numbers will show it with the parts also. (You should edit those to also use `\oldthechapter` instead if it bothers you.)

To make your chapter 5 work, you can call `\let\thechapter\oldthechapter` before `\chapter{Chapter Five}` and again `\def\thechapter{\thepart.\oldthechapter}` before the next chapter.

Comment: Depending on your workflow, it may be best to redefine `\part` so that it calls the `\def\thechapter...` command, and define a new command that both resets `\thechapter` and inserts a blank line into the TOC.

Comment: Thank you! That explains very well why it didn't work. I've managed to edit everything such that it it works as I wanted. Sorted it out for headers, headings, sections, figures, and tables. The only thing I haven't managed to fix is, if I \Cref a chapter which is included in a part, it gets prefixed with the part number (e.g. I.1).  It's not a massive issue, but it would be cool to iron that one out too.

Comment: With that info, another approach is needed. I will post a second answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `\counterwithin`. I didn't test for headers, not knowing how you want them, but if there's any problem, it should be easy to solve.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}

%% Titles
\usepackage[newparttoc, explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\counterwithin{chapter}{part}\vspace{3pc}\raggedleft\scshape\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename~\arabic{chapter}}
  {0.2em}
  {\raggedleft\normalfont\scshape\huge #1}
  [\vspace{2pc}]

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\titlerule[2pt]\centering\scshape\bfseries\Huge}
  {Part \thepart}
  {0.5em}
  {\centering\normalfont\itshape\Huge#1}
  [\titlerule\vspace{1em}]

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]
{\vspace{1.2em}\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace{1.5em}}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}%[\hfill]%[ ]

\pagestyle{empty}
\author{My Self}
\title{ToC Test}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle

\mainmatter
\tableofcontents
\part{Part One}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\chapter{Chapter Two}

\part{Part Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\chapter{Chapter Four}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works well also. I've accepted the other answer because it had the explanation of why it wasn't working, and I was really interested in it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The [OP's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507008/using-titletoc-to-redefine-chapter-toc-entry-as-part-number-chapter/507033?noredirect=1#comment1281413_507033) clarified that the only thing that should be changed should be the ToC listing, and nothing else. So my [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507033/119) is less than optimal because everywhere the counter for `\thechapter` is used what shows up will be effected. In particular, when labels are written to the `.aux` file it will include also the part information making it show up also in calls to `\ref`.

In this case the easiest thing to do would be to get your hands dirty and actually create a new chapter command which *adds* the part info *only* to the `.toc` file and otherwise behaves exactly like the ordinary `\chapter`. To do so, you can first dive into the document class you are using (which is `book.cls`), and see that `\chapter` is defined by

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

There are of course other commands involved in building the `\chapter` command, but the one that concerns us, where the ToC entry is written, is in `\@chapter`, where the `\addcontentsline` command is called. Specifically it reads

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
       {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
```

So all we need to do is to create a new command that does exactly the samething as `\chapter` except swap out the `\numberline{\thechapter}` bit with `\numberline{\thepart.\thechapter}`. If you always want to use this particular format in the ToC, we can just patch `\@chapter` by redefining it. But we want to also have the possibility of `\chapter{Chapter Five}` that doesn't show the part info. So we will define a new command called `\pchapter` that does everything like `\chapter` except this one minor addition.

The following code makes this change. (Note for convenience I removed the formatting commands for `titlesec` and `titletoc`; they should not be effected by the code, since `titlesec` patches `\@makechapterhead` to achieve the formatting, which we still call in the new `\@pchapter`.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\makeatletter
% The \pchapter command differs from \chapter only in changing to call 
% to \@chapter to \@pchapter
\newcommand\pchapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
            \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@pchapter\@schapter}
% As discussed above, the \@pchapter command only changes in how it calls 
% \addcontentsline
\def\@pchapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thepart.\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\title{ToC Test}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle

\mainmatter

\tableofcontents

\part{Part One}
% Calls to \pchapter records I.1 and I.2 in the ToC
\pchapter{Chapter One}
\pchapter{Chapter Two}

\part{Part Two}
\pchapter{Chapter Three}
\pchapter{Chapter Four}

% Call to \chapter records 5 in the ToC
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\end{document}
```

You will probably still need to use `titletoc` or at least do something to make enough room for the labels in the ToC.

Comment: Completely as an aside: as to your original problem of trying to visually distinguish chapters within parts with chapters outside parts in the TOC, have you considered just inserting something (like a line or a fleuron) between parts? You can do this with  `\addtocontents{toc}{stuff to add}`, though you should beware of [addtocontents writing stuff out of order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10291/addtocontents-at-end-of-document-not-getting-written-to-toc-file/10297#10297) which can happen.

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much for all the help! It is exactly what I needed. Also, your explanations are very clear, I really appreciate that. I did not consider adding something between parts, but now that you have mentioned I also did that, and it looks really cool. I'm also keeping the part prefix though, I want the separation to be as clear as possible (it's for my thesis, so not taking any risks). Thank you again!