# Chapter numbering with two parts as: I.1, I.2.. II.1, II.2,

Tags: numbering, chapters, parts

I am working in a report class for my thesis that has two parts (say part I and part II). I would like to have my Chapter numbering for instance as: I.1, I.2, ... II.1, II.2 etc. I now have that the chapter numbering just continues (so part II starts with chapter 10), I know I can 'reset' the chapter number so that part II starts with chapter 1 again, but is there a way to put the par t number in front?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well as far as I see, this only resets the chapter number (and that I know how to do), but it does not change the chapter name from Chapter "1" to Chapter "I.1"

Comment: @ClaireWagenaar try the solution with `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithin{chapter}{part}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using titletoc to redefine chapter toc entry as part number + chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507008/using-titletoc-to-redefine-chapter-toc-entry-as-part-number-chapter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\counterwithin{chapter}{part}`. Using the unstarred version of `\ccounterwithin`, the command `\thechapter` is automatically renewed as you want it.

Here's a complete example.

```
\documentclass{report}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
\begin{document}
\part{First part}
\chapter{Chapter I.1}
\chapter{Chapter I.2}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{Chapter II.1}
\chapter{Chapter II.2}
\end{document}
```

The first chapter of the second part looks like this:

[image]